Logstash import with nested type
I'm trying to import parent-child data into ES.
Here is my logstash config file:
input{
    jdbc{
        jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/library/postgresql-42.7.4.jar"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://185.**.**.28:5432/feed"
        jdbc_user => "airflow"
        jdbc_password => "**"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        statement => "select distinct source from public.news"
    }
}
filter{
jdbc_streaming {
jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/library/postgresql-42.7.4.jar"
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://185.**.**.28:5432/feed"
jdbc_user => "airflow"
jdbc_password => "**"
jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
parameters => {"source" => "source"}
statement => "select title,article, url, views from public.news where source = :source limit 10"
target => "posts"

}
mutate{
    remove_field => ["@version","@timestamp"]
}
}
output{
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => ["https://172.21.0.2:9200"]
        ssl_certificate_authorities => '/usr/library/http_ca.crt'
        ssl_verification_mode => "full"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "*****"
        index => "content2"
        document_id => "%{source}"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}

and here is the index mapping which has been created automatically:`
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "posts": {
        "properties": {
          "article": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
...
  }
}


Questions:

How to assign to posts  property  nested type
How to make posts subattribute of source?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you

Tldr;
What you see is an index being create with the default mapping from elasticsearch.
You will need to explicitly tell elasticsearch what the mapping of your index is before ingesting documents.
This can be done via:

Creating the index via api
Creating an index template

Demo
Creating an index via the api with nested type
I am creating the following index 79084663 with posts field as a nested field.
This operation ought to be done before you are sending any documents.
PUT 79084663/
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "source":{
        "type": "text"
      },
      "posts": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "url": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "article": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

